# flexjson deserialization in play framework

Tags: playframework-2.3, flexjson

I am trying to use flexjson in a playframework java project. But I am unable to deserialize json string to object. I am getting Could not load class exception while trying to deserialize caused by class not fount exception. I am using google guice for dependency injection does it have any thing to do with this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after upgrading the lib to 3.1